# A question related to random times and uniformly integrable martingales

Tags: functional-analysis, stochastic-processes, stochastic-analysis

$\rho$ is a random (not stopping) time. For every uniformly integrable martingale $(M_t)$, we have $E[|M_{\rho}|]\leq E[|M_{\infty}|]$. We want to show that $E[M_{\rho}]=E[M_{\infty}]$. I do not understand the proof for this. First, it suffices to apply our hypothesis to any martingale $(M_t)$ taking values in $[0,1]$ (Why?). Then
\begin{align}
 E[M_{\rho}] &\leq E[M_{\infty}]\\
 E[1-M_{\rho}] &\leq E[1-M_{\infty}] \\
 E[M_{\rho}] &= E[M_{\infty}].
\end{align}
The last equality follows from the sums on both sides amounts to 1 (what does this mean?).

Secondly, what can we tell about a martingale belongs to $\mathcal{H}^1$ (Banach space with norm $\int_0^{\infty} \sup_{t\geq 0}|M_t|<\infty$), and another martingale is uniformly integrable, I mean how they are related?